# Drupal views query using group by and sum

Tags: sql, group-by, view

I have thought about and played about with D7 views module for quite a while but I cannot get it working.

What I want to simple group-by and sum use if you see SQL below:

table

```
　　name　        age             sex

　　Los　         20　             1

　　San　         25　             0

　　Lan　         30　　           0

    Bos　         23　            1

　　mini          28              1
```

SQL:

```
　　SELECT sex,sum(age) FROM `msg_info` group by sex
```

result:

```
　　sex       sum(age)　　

　　0　　　　   55

　　1　　　　   71
```

I have tried to use "aggregation" and "query setting"(distinct) to get the table like that But I just can't. There is a "pure distinct" query setting under "adanced" which showed only one row at the end. I thought that's going to help but not really.

The real data has more columns than the example I gave here. Aggregation settings appeared be for every field which defaultly had a value being "group field result together". I had been playing with this. I set the "sum" for the field that I want to do SUM for. It's just no go.

Maybe anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want sum of age, why are you using group by sex? remove sex in select and remove group by and it will be work

Comment: Group by is the first thing I need. Sum itself is not serving the goal.

Comment: You are right. I had false understanding of group-by. It didn't merge duplicated fields. But sum did. So it worked. If I leave sex in the select, I have exactly what I need. So in Drupal aggregation, I don't need to use provided "group by field", only use aggregation, it worked.